# Why Error? - Posting Photo from FacebookSDK iOS ShareDialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I post a photo to Facebook, why error?

-facebook iOS SDK ver 3.19
-facebook App ver 17.0
-iOS ver -iOS7.1.2 -iOS8.0

```
BOOL canPresent = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos];

FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];
params.photos = @[targetImage];

BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
if (canPresent) {
    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                                          clientState:nil
                                                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

                                                                  if (error) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                                  } else {
                                                                      NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                                  }
                                                              }];
    isSuccessful = (appCall  != nil);
```

Photos to Facebook can be posted. However, an error is returned always.

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=103 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 103.)" UserInfo=0x1782e3a00 {error_reason=(
    {
    result = 1;
}
), error_description=An unknown error occurred., app_id=434867889904974, error_code=103}
```

Why return error?
This error, ignoring OK?

Comment: Did you get any luck with this one? I'm getting same error code when I try to post picture using [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:clientState:handler:my_handler];

Comment: im also having the same error. did you manage to solve?